# ¿como soluciono el error con com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage?

Tags: java, android-studio, firestore

tengo un proyecto en Android Studio, y cuando lo quiero exportar en APK me lanza el siguiente error:

> ```
> Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebugAndroidTest'.
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath'.
>    > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:.
>      Required by:
>          project :app > com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:7.2.0
>
> Possible solution:
>  - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at
> ```
>
> https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

este es el codigo que tengo en build.gradle:

```
// FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:7.2.0'

// FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:7.2.0'

// FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:7.2.0'
```

Cual podria ser una solucion a este error?

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías agregar tu archivo `app/build.gradle` completo pulsando en [edit]?